# C++ Reading file with some information omitted

Tags: c++, file, vector

I have a text file structured like this:

```
G 15324 2353
D 23444 
Q 23433 32565
```

I want to store each piece of information into a variable and contain it within a vector:

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("file.txt");
vector<SomeClass> test;
SomeClass temp;
while (fin >> temp.code >> temp.datapoint>> temp.dataleague)
{
      test.push_back(temp);
}
```

However, within the file sometimes the third value (*temp.dataleague*) is omitted and left blank. Obviously my code above will not work as it will just put garbage within that field. How do I do this when it's uncertain if the third field will contain a value or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using:

```
std::istream::getline
```

This will allow you to get each line inside a buffer and then process it as you wish.

```
char buffer[256];
fin.getline(buffer,256);
```

You can then parse the different fields using:

```
std::string line = std::string(buffer);
int index = line.find(' ');
if (index>0)
    std::cout << "My value is: " << line.substr(0,index);
```

With you example:

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("file.txt");
vector<SomeClass> test;
SomeClass temp;
char buffer[256];

while (!fin.eof())
{
    fin.getline(buffer,256);
    auto line = std::string(buffer);
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    int start = 0, end = line.find(' ');
    while (end!=-1)
    {
        tokens.push_back(line.substr(start,end-1));
        start = end +1;
        end = line.find(' ');
    }
    if (start<line.size())
        tokens.push_back(line.substr(start));
    if (tokens.size()==3)
    {
        test.code = tokens[0];
        test.datapoint= tokens[1];
        test.dataleague= tokens[2];
        test.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.  Read the whole line in and then parse it on the known delimiter (' ').  Once you know how many items were on the line you can use istringstream to pull them out in an expected way.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream fin("file.txt");
  vector<SomeClass> test;
  string line;

  while (getline(fin, line))
  {
     istringstream iss(line);
     char code = 'X';
     int datapoint = 99999, dataleague = 99999;
     size_t n = count(line.begin(), line.end(), ' ');
     if (n == 0) iss >> code;
     else if (n == 1) iss >> code >> datapoint;
     else if (n == 2) iss >> code >> datapoint >> dataleague;

     SomeClass temp(code, datapoint, dataleague);
     test.push_back(temp);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, simple way to approach this. Thanks